# How to "group together" each paragraph in Google Docs (or "protect it" so that it goes together on the same page)?

Tags: google-docs

Short question: In Google Docs, can I make a paragraph not span 2 pages?  That is, the same paragraph will show on one page only.

Details:

In Google Docs, to edit my resume (CV), I was going to add "page breaks" so that each paragraph will go on the same page, instead of having 5 lines on one page and 2 lines on the next page, but then I realize that if somebody gets the resume, and added 5 lines of comments or header in the front of my resume, then everything could go strange: there might be a page with 3 lines, and then the "page break" will go into effect and start a new page.

So I realize a more proper thing to do is to "group" the paragraph content together, so that each paragraph goes on the same page.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Suggest the use of the comments feature instead  of inserting comments as inline text. See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129?hl=en

Comment: You mean the insertion of those 5 lines of comments in front? Because sometimes the person who passes the resume around doesn't really care, so it is beyond my control

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Are you sharing your resume or sending / uploading it as attachment? Are you able to see those 5 lines of comments?

Comment: Usually, people ask me for my resume. It could be recruiters or headhunters.  Sometimes, they get the resume and won't care too much of how it looks like, or they may not know that adding some lines in front will have that side effect, so they may print it out or pass it around without knowing it.

Comment: Format > Line spacing > Keep with next

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### 2020 Update

***This is now available!***

Every answer here is out-of-date except [@AlexanderPozdneev's](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/139714/47763) (+1), which mentions the new ***Keep with next*** menu item.  There also is a ***Keep lines together*** and ***Prevent single lines***:

[image]

This is very useful and sure to be appreciated by the community.

Comment: Can't believe my eyes! 10 years passed and they actually did do that!!!

Answer (score 15):

> So I realize a more proper thing to do is to "group" the paragraph content together, so that each paragraph goes on the same page. Is there a way to do it?

No. Several years ago it used to be possible, but the `Keep with next` feature was removed and hasn't been added back despite many requests. You may want to subscribe to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/hPgOC8XFf30

Use the Feedback tool to request this feature:

- Open a Google Docs document ➜ Help ➜ Report a problem

Answer (score 6):

You can change style of each paragraph to "Subtitle", which makes Google Docs keep all of that paragraph and its' preceding heading on same page.

Comment: This busts anything which might be looking at the structure of the document (to create an outline or TOC, perhaps) but is a clever workaround if that's not a concern.

Comment: This works! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Put the cursor to a paragraph you want to keep with the next paragraph
2. <kbd>Format</kbd> > <kbd>Line spacing</kbd> > <kbd>Keep with next</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about two slightly different questions here. First of all the *Keep with next* feature, which sadly has been removed. This would have tried keeping your paragraph together, or move the entire paragraph to the next page.

Secondly you are talking about someone adding text in front of your resume, and thusly shifting the content of your resume. The correct thing to do here is to provide them with a non-editable resume. The resume should be your document with your formatting, and should not be editable by them at all.

When in need of a resume I almost always send the PDF version of it, this allows for me to control the formatting, and for them to annotate the PDF if they are so inclined. Then if they print it out or hand it out, you are sure that you are presented in the way you wanted your resume to be.

Comment: no, no matter what, they would like to edit my resume, because they always add their header, so that they can use my head to make money. ("they" refers to the headhunters)

Comment: @太極者無極而生  The proper way to add their header would be to add an entire front page, and still leave your resume untouched. I would consider anyone editing my resume unprofessional.

Comment: Interestingly, in Workplace.SE answers go in the opposite way: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/113658/i-prepared-my-cv-in-latex-and-exported-it-to-pdf-how-to-deal-with-a-recruiter-w , although answers to other questions may hold conflicting views.

Answer (score 2):

If the paragraph isn't too large, and if it has a small break in it such as if you're naming off things you can try Shift+Enter instead of a full break with simply Enter. On this forum post its not visible, but give it a try on your docs.

Example: (Shift+Enter)
Text Stoof

If the paragraph goes 1/3rd into the next page however, I've noticed it tends to just split it, which from an editing perspective makes sense.

Comment: This worked for me, don't know why it is down-voted.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this, but I was having a problem with a word document that I had imported into Google as a Google doc. The imported 'paragraphs' were stuck together generating large blank white space in my Google doc. I fixed the problem by reformatting as normal text. However, this suggests a workaround. Use word to create you 'kept together text' and bring it into Google. My guess is that since Google docs used to have the feature, it is still there. Google just removed any tool to turn it on or off.

Comment: I concur with the down-vote for two reasons:
One, an untested speculation was presented here.
Two, I tested it, and the speculative suggestion doesn't appear to work.