# How can I do "page break before" paragraph formatting in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I see that "keep with next" was something a user could do at one point in Docs, but no longer. Can users do other paragraph formatting options, especially **Page break before** a specific text style?

What I'm trying to avoid is having to insert page breaks manually. I want "page break before" to be a component of a paragraph style.

Comment: You can add a page break and include that when you make copies

Comment: Zach, thanks but that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid: having to insert page breaks manually. I want "page break before" to be a component of a paragraph style.

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82771/88163, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/82496/88163

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the capability is there, found this Google Docs extentions that makes it possible to set "page break before": https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paragraph-styles%20/pbfegackndhdneogcnlhhihgkphkggdh?hl=en

Though it changes other style options as well...

[image]